# Is there a way to exlude SQL results that are ALMOST duplicates?

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have query that runs daily that shows old and new member addresses as they are updated. The query works fine except for the times when a USPS address match is done in our core system and just changes some of the abbreviations

For example:

Old Address - 1234 East Main Street
New Address - 1234 E Main St

I don't need to see these results.

I have tried removing based on unique fields in the core, however, the USPS match process creates all new fields so the query can't remove based on that information.

The main SP for this is:

```
INSERT INTO @results  
SELECT   
distinct i.INDIVIDUAL_ID, 
 i.FIRST_NAME,  
 i.MIDDLE_NAME,  
 i.LAST_NAME, 
 i.D1NAME,    
 CurrentAddress.ADDRESS1,  
 PreviousAddress.ADDRESS1,  
 CurrentAddress.ADDRESS2,  
 PreviousAddress.ADDRESS2,  
 CurrentAddress.ADDRESS3,  
 PreviousAddress.ADDRESS3,  
 CurrentAddress.CITY,  
 PreviousAddress.CITY,  
 CurrentAddress.STATE,  
 PreviousAddress.STATE,  
 CurrentAddress.ZIP_STR,  
 PreviousAddress.ZIP_STR,  
 CurrentAddress.ZIP4_STR,  
 PreviousAddress.ZIP4_STR,  
 CurrentAddress.COUNTRY,  
 PreviousAddress.COUNTRY  
 FROM INDIVIDUAL i  
 INNER JOIN MEMBERSHIPPARTICIPANT mpt  
 ON i.INDIVIDUAL_ID = mpt.INDIVIDUAL_ID  
 AND i.DL_LOAD_DATE = mpt.DL_LOAD_DATE  
 INNER JOIN AGR_MEMBERTOTAL_TODAY m  
 ON mpt.MEMBER_NBR = m.MEMBER_NBR  
 AND mpt.DL_LOAD_DATE = m.DL_LOAD_DATE  
 INNER JOIN BRANCH b  
 ON i.BRANCH_NBR = b.BRANCH_NBR  
 CROSS APPLY dbo.GetCurrentAddress(i.INDIVIDUAL_ID, @latestDate)  AS CurrentAddress  
 CROSS APPLY dbo.GetCurrentAddress(i.INDIVIDUAL_ID, @previousDate) AS PreviousAddress  
 WHERE i.DL_LOAD_DATE = @latestDate  
 AND ( m.OPN_LN_ALL_CNT > 0 OR m.OPN_SV_ALL_CNT > 0 )  
 order by  i.FIRST_NAME asc    


DELETE @results
WHERE Address1_Today = Address2_Yesterday
AND Address2_Today = Address1_Yesterday

SELECT * 
FROM @results  
WHERE (Address1_Today != Address1_Yesterday  
  OR Address2_Today != Address2_Yesterday  
  OR Address3_Today != Address3_Yesterday  
  OR City_Today != City_Yesterday  
  OR State_Today != State_Yesterday  
  OR ZipCode_Today != ZipCode_Yesterday  
  --OR FullZip_Today != FullZip_Yesterday     
  OR Country_Today != Country_Yesterday)
```

I'd like to remove the almost duplicate rows

For example:

```
Old Address - 1234 East Main Street
New Address - 1234 E Main St
```

Comment: SQL does not have built in mechanisms to define "almost duplicates".  You need to figure out the logic you want to use and apply it using the right tool.  I would suggest address standardization software for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built in way to test via SQL, and it will have to be defined by logic via procedure. The first thing I'd do is group the substrings in both Old Address and New Address by count of those substrings. The ones where the counts equal each other at the row level, you can split by space and break up the address. Think of each address field as three parts [street_nbr, street_nm, street_suffix]. The street_nm can have an abbreviated prefix, which is why grouping the count of substrings is important thereby increasing the count past 3. Secondary lookup tables that match words/abbreviations that you identify can then be used to "un-duplicate" those suffixes and prefixes.

```
    CREATE TABLE lookup_abbreviations(
        unabbreviated_name varchar(50),
        abbreviated_name varchar(50));

    INSERT INTO lookup_abbreviations(unabbreviated_name, abbreviated_name)
        VALUES ('East', 'E')
    INSERT INTO lookup_abbreviations(unabbreviated_name, abbreviated_name)
        VALUES ('Street', 'St');

-- Use Cross Applies and functions(LEN, LEFT, RIGHT, CHARINDEX, SUBSTRING) to split the address
-- into equal parts. This is where you'll have to figure out the best logic for grouping.

    SELECT DISTINCT

        Old_Street_Nbr = SUBSTRING(Old_Address, CHARINDEX(' ', Old_Address))
        Old_Street_Nm_Prefix = CASE WHEN /*Here is where the count of substrings is tested*/ END
        Old_Street_Nm = CASE WHEN /*Here is where the count of substrings is tested*/ END
        Old_Street_Suffix = []
    INTO #AbbreviatonSort
    FROM Results;

    SELECT 
       Old_Street_Nbr    ,
       Old_Street_Nm_Prefix  = CASE 
                                  WHEN Old_Street_Nm_Prefix IN (SELECT abbreviated_name from 
                               lookup_abbreviations)
                                 THEN (SELECT unabbreviated_name from 
                                       lookup_abbreviations WHERE abbreviated_name = 
                                       Old_Street_Nm_Prefix)
                               ELSE Old_Street_Nm_Prefix
                               END
    INTO #SortedAddresses
    FROM #AbbreviationSort
    ;

    SELECT DISTINCT * FROM
   (
   SELECT Old_Street_Nbr, Old_Prefix FROM #SortedAddresses
   UNION ALL
   SELECT New_Street_Nbr, New_Prefix FROM #SortedAddresses
   ) AS DupSearch
```